# hiding field -reference option limit

Tags: entities

Helloo !
I am using the D7 reference option limit module. I have two fields "primary" and "secondary" and I managed to reduce the choices of secondary based on the value of primary using this module. Both of them are required field in the user registration form.

I have a small question, when I set no value for primary, I get for the secondary field: No options are available for the current form values. Try selecting different values for the following fields: Primary.  This is the good behaviour that I want but I want to hide secondary when no value is set for primary instead of displaying this message..

Is that possible? In other words I want to keep secondary hidden until primary has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try any alter functions to implement ?

if you can try with alter then try `#states` in `hook_form_alter()` to hide field, if primary field default value is empty/null.

here is e.g

```
/**
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @param type $form_id
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
    // Hide secondary field.
    if (isset($form['secondary_field'])) {
      $form['secondary_field']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => array(
          'input[name="primary_field"]' => array('!value' => ''),
        ),
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

`'input[name="primary_field"]' => array('!value' => ''),` change this as per need i.e if its select list then `'select[name="primary_field"]' => array('!value' => ''),` etc.

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very muchh